# Injecting one of data repositories in Service layer in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

In my web app I have two different data storages - db and file. In `application.properties` I can set which one I want to use. I use `Spring Data JPA` for accessing object from db, so my `DataBaseRepository` extends `CrudRepository`.

I want to inject one inteface of Repository in `Service` layer, and 
implementation will depend on chosen profile(in application.properties). 
Problem is that my `FileRepository` doesn't implement `CrudRepository`, so my repositories haven't common interface for injecting.

**Approach 1**:Suppose, that my `FileRepository` extends `CrudRepository`(and I mark FileRepository with `@NoRepositoryBean`)

**Problem**: my implementation of `FileRepository` must implement many methods, which I don't need(I don't know if it is normal approach and it is worked)

**Approach2**:don't use `CrudRepository` interface

**Problem**: writing many boilerplate code

So, please tell me about another approaches,if they exist in such situation, or say which one is better. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds to me like a simple case for interfaces... you have a data storage interface which defines methods for data access and then your `DataBaseRepository` and `FileRepository` can both implement your interface.

Comment: But I want to use CrudRepository for avoiding writing boilerplate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a CustomCrudRepository that extends CrudRepository and a BaseRepository.The BaseRepository interface contains every method that has to be supported by any implementation. Most likely copy the signature from CrudRepository. Than inject based on the BaseRepository.

Hard to explain so see the following example without generics. You can add them on your own.

```
public interface BaseRepo {
    // common methods
    long count();

    ...
}

@NoRepositoryBean
interface CustomCrudRepository extends CrudRepository, BaseRepo {

}

interface EntityRepository extends CustomCrudRepository {

}

class FileRepository implements BaseRepo {

    @Override
    public long count() {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Service
class SomeService {

    @Autowired
    private BaseRepo repo;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm gonna attempt it.  As I understand EntityRepository is optional?

Comment: EntityRepository is just an example for an interface for a real jpa Entity.

Comment: I'm gonna rename CustomCrudRepository to UserRepository and delete annotation. So UserRepository - it is interface for real jpa Entity. It is right?

Comment: CustomCrudRepository should be extend by each spring data jpa repository and the NoRepositoryBean annotation has to be there. Every class where you would have extended CrudRepository should now extend this interface. Except the FileRepository since this is no jpa thing it should extend BaseRepo. You can change names as you like.

Comment: Last question: it is normal if my BaseRepo has saveAndFlush() method and FileRepository class contains it? In FileRepository class it looks very strange.

Comment: If none JPA repositories should not have this method, just don't add it to BaseRepo. The BaseRepo should only contain methods, that you want to have for non JPA repositories. File streams in java can flush, so it would not be totally wrong to have it there. But I don't think this is needed.

Comment: I use it while registering user with unique login, in my service layer I invoke saveAndFlush in try catch block, and catch ConstraintViolationException. then throw custom exception.

Comment: Than you have to do it. But in my opinion having to flush is in most cases an architectural issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. Good luck)